# matlab submatrices in loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, submatrix

I have a  118800x6 matrix. the first column contains values from 1 to 99 (there are 1200 rows for each value). now I need to create a new matrix that contains 900 random rows (all of the previous column; the rows are extracted from the original matrix) for each 99 values. I tried with a for loop but that means that I have to write 99 rows of code...there is a faster way? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The all of the previous column requirement has me puzzled, but I think ‘randperm‘ will help you out.

Comment: Why does a for loop mean you have to write 99 rows of code?

Comment: Is there any way we can see a sample of what the 99 lines of code might look like?

Comment: @johnish - why would we want to look at these 99 lines of code?

Comment: @Shai - I don't need to see all 99 lines... 50 or 60 would probably be enough for me to get my mind around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your matrix is called `M`:

```
for num = 1:99
    %Extract only rows that have the correct number in column one
    subsample = M(M(1, :) == num, :);
    %Randomly change the order of the rows of this subsample
    shuffledsubsample = subsample(randperm(1200), :);
    %Only keep the first 900 rows
    final(:,:,num) = shuffledsubsample(1:900, :);
end
```